# How to stretch a fabric canvas to the full width of its parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, fabricjs

[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEllP.png)
I have a fabric canvas placed inside a parent div. how can i stretch the canvas to the full width and height of its parent

Here is what my code look likes:

```
<div class="design_editor_div">       
    <canvas id="c"  width="500" height="500" style="border-style:dashed;border-color:#a1a1a1;text- 
     align:center;border-width:initial;"></canvas>
    <img src="{{ '2.png' | asset_url }}"  title="" alt="" style="display: none" id="img">         
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css and select the child element of the div as such:

```css
canvas > div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   
}
```

For sure, use a seperate stylesheet and include a `<link>path-to-stylesheet</link>` in the head or `<style> css... </style>` tags in the head of your html document. Inline CSS styles should be reserved for elements that you need to alter that are very unique, such as making part of a  or `<p>` element `<strong>` or `<u>`. Including many `<style>` tags inline will impact the readability of the tag.